# ApplicationData.GetPublisherCacheFolder returns two different folders in two different apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm trying to use the PublisherCacheFolder feature in UWP.
Both apps have the same publisher name
And have specified access in their manifest.

Code:

```
StorageFolder mainFolder = ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder("MainFolder");
```

The first app returns a MainFolder with different path compared to the second one.

ex:

1) "C:\Users\abclogin\AppData\Local\Publishers\9mstedc7shqft\MainFolder"

2) "C:\Users\abclogin\AppData\Local\Publishers\cm3j9gb0z0ryj\MainFolder"

Shouldn't both of them return the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was I did not associate the applications with the store which was the issue.

Just associate the apps to the same store account and it will start working.